# Smalltalk, text editor value

Tags: smalltalk

How I can insert `OrderedCollection` into the text editor? I tried to do something like that:

```
texeditor value:list printString
```

where list is my `OrderedCollection`. The result was

> OrderedCollection('4''2''1')

in the text editor, but I would like to have as a result, only the values stored in the collection, so that the text editor will show:

> '4''2''1'

without the "`OrderedCollection`".

Comment: (1) What implementation of smalltalk is this? (2) please format your code as code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try soemthing like this:

```
textEditor value: (list inject: String new into: [:string :each |
   string, each printString])
```